# Highchart HeatMap with Dates

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to implement heatmap using highcharts.I want something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/ycz4engq/

The above example uses data.csv option of highcharts and works fine. I want to be able to specify data in the series option but it wouldn't work. How do I specify data in the series option to get the above chart? Why am I not able to do this?

```
series: [{
        data: [[2015-01-01,4,2.5],[2015-01-02,5,4.5],[2015-05-01,5,3.2]],
        borderWidth: 0,
        colsize: 24 * 36e5, // one day
    }]
```

Comment: Your dates need to be either an epoch time stamp, or a Date.UTC object - a date string won't work.

Comment: I tried Date.UTC too, but that didn't work. It throws an error on console

Comment: What error does it throw? Set up a fiddle or other live example.

Comment: While setting up a fiddle, I did the same thing as before and it worked! Must have got something other mixed up when I tried before. Here is the example in case some one needs it - http://jsfiddle.net/ycz4engq/1/